# Delete Link Points Outside Datafile at xxxxx

Tags: mysql, database

I was having a problem with MySQL crashing on a VPS for unknown reasons. I ran a repair on the databases using the following

> sudo mysqlcheck -u user -p --repair --use-frm --all-databases

I received a number of messages including info messages stating

> Delete link points outside datafile at (location)

What does this mean?

Comment: I hope useful: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?26,416935,416935

Comment: Thanks. I'd actually looked at that one, but I'm not in a replication scenario.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for this problem?

Comment: Ohh geez, I'm sorry, I don't recall at all how I fixed this.